# Как сделать так чтобы select2 при выборе не отображал уже выбранные элементы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

При мультиселекте в списке отображаются уже выбранные элементы, какой опцией их убирать?
Ещё ищу метод которым из js  можно очистить все выбранные элементы, перепробовал все что удалось нагуглить помогает только дестрой и новое навешивание

Comment: у тебя два мультиселекта? один полный, а во втором, то что ты выбрал?

Answer (score 1):

А они у тебя активные? По идее они должны присутствовать без возможности их повторного выбора.

В любом случае при рендере списка select2 он создаёт в конце страницы

```
<span class="select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--open"...
```

В нём есть

```
<ul class="select2-results__options">
```

В котором выбранные элементы выглядят так

```
<li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">...</li>
```

Т.е. имеют

```
aria-selected="true"
```

Всё, что тебе нужно, это скрыть этот элемент средствами CSS.